# It is possible to obtain non-zero padding fft from zero padding fft?

Tags: fft

This is just a question out of my curiosity, normally we do not do this
I have a x(n)=[1 2 3]

```
y(n) = fft[1 2 3 0] =  6 + 0i  -2 - 2i   2 + 0i  -2 + 2i %zero padding
y'(n) = fft([1 2 3]) = 6 + 0i  -1.5 + 0.87i  -1.5 - 0.87i
```

I used Matlab to generate these results.
My question is there way to obtain y'(n) from y(n)?

Comment: You mean other than taking the inverse fft, removing the zeros and then doing another fft?

Comment: yes, some kind of direct calculation

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Zero padding allows interpolation in the frequency domain. You can get the same result directly in the frequency domain using circular sin(x)/x interpolation. See for example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula